# Using jquery to make a POST, how to properly supply 'data' parameter?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to make an ajax call as a POST, it's going to go to my servlet. I want to send parameterized data, like the following:

```
var mydata = 'param0=some_text&param1=some_more_text';
```

I supply this as the 'data' parameter of my jquery ajax() call. So this should be inserted in the body of the POST, right? (I mean, not appended to my 'mysite/save' url?):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mysite/save',
    type: 'POST',
    data: mydata
});
```

it appears to work correctly. In my servlet, I am just dumping all received parameters, and I see them all come through nicely:

```
private void printParams(HttpServletRequest req) {
    Enumeration paramNames = req.getParameterNames();
    while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) { 
        // print each param key/val here.
    }
}
```

also, I should url encode my data string manually before use, right? Like:

```
var mydata = 'param0=' + urlencode('hi there!');
mydata += '&param1=' + urlencode('blah blah');
mydata += '%param2=' + urlencode('we get it');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

An easier way is to provide the `data` property as an object, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'mysite/save',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { param0:'hi there!', param1:'blah blah', param2:'we get it' }
});
```

Otherwise, yes you should encode it, as anything with an `&` for example would screw things up very quickly. Providing it as an object represents a much clearer/simpler approach though, in my opinion anyway.

You can also space it out and retrieve properties from other places inline, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'mysite/save',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { 
          param0: $('#textbox0').val(), 
          param1: $('#textbox1').val(), 
          param2: $('#textbox2').val()
        }
});
```

*Edit:* If you're curious how jQuery does this encoding internally, it's using [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) (which you can use directly as well) to encode the object to a string, called [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L209), and the guts [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L507).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a form, you can also do `var data = jQuery("#myForm").serialize();` which puts it in a form that `jQuery.ajax` can understand and use. Otherwise, use the object literal described in Nick's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need this part:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    BarcodeNumber: $('#my-input').val(),
    StatusId: $('[name="StatusId"]').val()
}),
```

Full object :

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "/api/create",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            BarcodeNumber: $('#my-input').val(),
            StatusId: $('[name="StatusId"]').val()
        }),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (textStatus== "success") {
                alert(data);
                // Handel success
            }
            else {
                // Handel response error
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              //Handel connection error
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

can this help you

```
function CallPageSync(url, data) {
    var response;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        timeout: 4000,
        success: function(result) {
            response = result;
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            response = "err--" + XMLHttpRequest.status + " -- " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText;
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

and you can call it like

```
response = CallPageSync(checkPageURL, "un=" + username);
```

Comment: I think he wants to know *how* to build the `data` parameter and not how to use `jQuery.ajax`.

Comment: just write it as you write it in URL :
"ID=10&Name=aaaaa"

Comment: defining submission type is better I think..
type: 'POST'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to URL encode POST variables. However if you are interacting with a database, you will want to make sure your variables are injection attack protected.

What you have will work, however as **Vivin** mentioned, if it's a form then the best way to do it is via `.serialize()`.

I use this a LOT personally for all my form submissions (done via `.ajax()`).