# How to pass parameters in GET requests with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

How should I be passing query string values in a jQuery Ajax request? I currently do them as follows but I'm sure there is a cleaner way that does not require me to encode manually.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.aspx?ajaxid=4&UserID=" + UserID + "&EmailAddress=" + encodeURIComponent(EmailAddress),
    success: function(response) {
        //Do Something
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
    }
});
```

I’ve seen examples where query string parameters are passed as an array but these examples I've seen don't use the `$.ajax()` model, instead they go straight to `$.get()`. For example:

```
$.get("ajax.aspx", { UserID: UserID , EmailAddress: EmailAddress } );
```

I prefer to use the $.ajax() format as it's what I’m used to (no particularly good reason - just a personal preference).

**Edit 09/04/2013:**

After my question was closed (as "Too Localised") i found a related (identical) question - with 3 upvotes no-less (My bad for not finding it in the first place):

[Using jquery to make a POST, how to properly supply 'data' parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066070/using-jquery-to-make-a-post-how-to-properly-supply-data-parameter)

This answered my question perfectly, I found that doing it this way is much easier to read & I don't need to manually use `encodeURIComponent()` in the URL or the DATA values (which is what i found unclear in bipen's answer). This is because the `data` value is encoded automatically via [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)). Just in case this can be of use to anyone else, this is the example I went with:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.aspx?ajaxid=4",
    data: { 
        "VarA": VarA, 
        "VarB": VarB, 
        "VarC": VarC
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {

    },
    error: function(xhr) {

    }
});
```

Comment: $.get is just a shortcut for $.ajax

Comment: except, your Edit 09/04/2013 is a post request :-) but it apparently works the same as GET.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

Use data option of ajax. You can send data object to server by `data` option in ajax and the `type` which defines how you are sending it (either `POST` or `GET`). The default type is `GET` method

Try this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax.aspx",
  type: "get", //send it through get method
  data: { 
    ajaxid: 4, 
    UserID: UserID, 
    EmailAddress: EmailAddress
  },
  success: function(response) {
    //Do Something
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
  }
});
```

And you can get the data by (if you are using PHP)

```
 $_GET['ajaxid'] //gives 4
 $_GET['UserID'] //gives you the sent userid
```

In aspx, I believe it is (might be wrong)

```
 Request.QueryString["ajaxid"].ToString();
```

Comment: you don't  need `encodeURIComponent`. jquery will do this for you.

Comment: @KlwWallace Nope. That's PHP (server side) depends on which servside language you are using. In PHP that's how we get the values of get request.

Comment: @bipen.  Roger that.  I deleted my comment so as not to confuse anyone.  Thx.

Comment: you need to convert the object into GET parameters with jQuery.param() function, so using jQuery you should use `data:$.param({ajaxid: 4, UserID: UserID, EmailAddress: EmailAddress})`, instead of `data: { 
    ajaxid: 4, 
    UserID: UserID, 
    EmailAddress: EmailAddress
  }`

Comment: how would I pass request body for this specific example?

Answer (score 23):

Put your params in the `data` part of the `ajax` call. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/TestPage.aspx",
    data: {"first": "Manu","Last":"Sharma"},
    success: function(response) {
        //Do Something
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is the syntax using jQuery `$.get`

```
$.get(url, data, successCallback, datatype)
```

So in your case, that would equate to,

```
var url = 'ajax.asp';
var data = { ajaxid: 4, UserID: UserID, EmailAddress: EmailAddress };
var datatype = 'jsonp';

function success(response) {
// do something here 
}

$.get('ajax.aspx', data, success, datatype)
```

**Note** 
`$.get` does not give you the opportunity to set an error handler. But there are several ways to do it either using [$.ajaxSetup()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/), [$.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) or chaining a `.fail` on your `$.get` like below

```
$.get(url, data, success, datatype)
 .fail(function(){
})
```

The reason for setting the datatype as 'jsonp' is due to browser same origin policy issues, but if you are making the request on the same domain where your javascript is hosted, you should be fine with datatype set to `json`.

If you don't want to use the jquery `$.get` then [see the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for `$.ajax` which allows room for more flexibility

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.aspx",
    type:'get',
    data: {ajaxid:4, UserID: UserID , EmailAddress: encodeURIComponent(EmailAddress)},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      //Do Something
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
    }
});
```

Depends on what datatype is expected, you can assign `html, json, script, xml`

Comment: your solution is helpful, but wondering how to define the variable ( `ID`)  ahead before passing it as parameter ? I have Q on SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192531/add-editable-textbox-to-specific-datapoint-in-a-chart. I progressed on this Q much further, where now I call a jquery dialog and call ajax to retrieve data from mysql. I am missing the link on how to retrieve the unique ID associated with each ***datapoint click***. Appreciate if you can help me out. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem where I specified `data` but the browser was sending requests to URL ending with `[Object object]`.

You should have `processData` set to `true`.

```
processData: true, // You should comment this out if is false or set to true
```

Comment: OMG, thanks. After 4 hours of searching and trying this finally fixed an issue here :-)

Answer (score 1):

The data property allows you to send in a string.  On your server side code, accept it as a string argument name "myVar" and then you can parse it out.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.aspx",
    data: [myVar = {id: 4, email: 'emailaddress', myArray: [1, 2, 3]}];
    success: function(response) {
    //Do Something
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you do `stringify`? jQuery's `ajax` implementation takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$.ajax()`, and if you don't want to put the parameters directly into the URL, use the `data:`. That's appended to the URL

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The data parameter of ajax method allows you send data to server side.On server side you can request the data.See the code

```
var id=5;
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "url of server side script",
    data:{id:id},
    success: function(res){
        console.log(res);
    },
error:function(error)
{
console.log(error);
}
});
```

At server side receive it using  $_GET variable.

```
$_GET['id'];
```