# Jquery ajax get method with parameter is not working in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, get-request

I want to call a web method using jquery ajax get method.but it is not getting called. below my javascript and code

**javascript:**

```
    function RetrievePassword() {
    var forgotEmail = $("#txtForgotEmail").val().trim();

    //call the ajax method to retrieve the password from the email address provided.
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.aspx/RetrievePassword?email=" + forgotEmail,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.d);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error while calling the server!");
        }
    });
}
```

**my code behind function**

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
    public static string RetrievePassword(string email)
    {
     //some code
}
```

Can anybody help me on this..

Comment: Are you sure you are including `j-query` reference ?

Comment: Please go through the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576548/jquery-how-to-pass-parameters-in-get-requests

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, `ASP.Net AJAX` page methods only support `POST` requests.

Below example is shown using `POST` request

*jQuery*

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.aspx/RetrievePassword",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{email:"' + forgotEmail + '"}',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error while calling the server!");
    }
});
```

C# Pagemethod

```
[WebMethod]        
public static void RetrievePassword(string email)
{
    //some code           
}
```

Remember to use ajax post data variable name as used in pagemethod's argument. As it's case-sesitive

Comment: I think you are wrong. I already sent Get request without parameters but with parameter I think is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

try this into your code :

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'URL',
                    data: "{ 'Keyword': '" + forgotEmail + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            console.log(item);
                            return {
                                item;
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        console.log(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

to be sure of your code, always go with `console.log();`

Answer (score 0):

try this in the `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
 ...
 <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
 </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

[ScriptModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.web.handlers.scriptmodule?view=netframework-4.8) is for manageing HTTP modules for AJAX functionality in ASP.NET.,and sometimes asp.net is loading this improperly. You have to include ScriptModule manually in `web.config`.

Reference:

[WebMethod not working. (language:Chinese)](https://blog.darkthread.net/blog/pagemethod-failed-under-sharepoint/)