# Ajax call returning whole page html in asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am working on asp.net web forms application. I am trying to make an ajax call to a web method in codebehind, but instead of returning the result, it returns the whole html page.

I am calling it on button click

```
 <input type="button" id="btnCallAPIFromClient" class="btn btn-success" value="Call API from Client"/>
```

My js script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //PageMethods.set_path(PageMethods.get_path() + '.aspx');
    $('#btnCallAPIFromClient').click(function() {
        alert('here');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/login/GetAccessToken',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                debugger;
                sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.access_token);
                alert(response.access_token);
            },
            // Display errors if any in the Bootstrap alert <div>
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

webmethod is:

```
   [WebMethod]
        public static string GetAccessToken()
        {
           return "abc";
        }
```

Comment: Notice `dataType: 'html',` try once with `dataType: "text",`

Comment: Also add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",dataType: "json"`

Comment: For someone really sure ajax structure forming in right way who could doubt ScriptModule not loading well. I have answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57250072/7786739).

Comment: My suggestion to anyone having these types of problems: please double check the routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have set the datatype as html.
Change the datatype to text as follows:

```
dataType: 'text'
```

And also in the success function change this line

```
sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.access_token);
```

To

```
sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", response);
```

Because you are not receiving data in json format. So this will be invalid.

Comment: @AsifHameed, have you tried what i've mentioned in comment ?

Comment: yes, I see this in the network tab of chrome:  {Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null,…}
ExceptionType
:
"System.InvalidOperationException"
Message
:
"Authentication failed."
StackTrace
:
null

Comment: Please do have a look ---> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized). Maybe this is what you are struggling at

Comment: Thanks  Prashant Pokhriyal