# Jquery Ajax get not passing values

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is driving me crazy...

```
$(document).on("click",".load",function(b){
  b.preventDefault();
  $.get("/url/get.php",{
    id: 123
  },
  function(a){
    $("#result").html(a);
  })
});
```

This loads the page as expected but when I do `print_r($_GET)` it shows it's empty... 
Any ideas?

Backend:

```
 if (isset($user) == false) {
     session_start();
     $path_to_root = "../";
     require($path_to_root."require/loads.php");
     $PDO = new PDO(DB_CONN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
     $user = new User($PDO);
 }
 $i = 0;
 print_r($_GET);
```

Comment: It may have something to do with your backend setup. That js looks fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery, How to pass parameters in get requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576548/jquery-how-to-pass-parameters-in-get-requests)

Comment: I posted my backend @AmmarCSE

Comment: That didn't help me @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz

Comment: Ok!! saw now the backend. Checking!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this way, using done() function:

```
$(document).on("click",".load",function(b){
  b.preventDefault();
  $.get("/url/get.php",{
    id: 123
  }).done(
  function(a){
    $("#result").html(a);
  })
});
```

As said in [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) that´s the way to send payload data with GET.

Anyway, you can also use ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/url/get.php",
  type: "get", //send it through get method
  data:{id:123},
  success: function(response) {
      $("#result").html(a);
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    $("#result").html("ERROR");
  }
});
```

Anyway, if you are still viewing those errors, the problem souhld be in your backend as @AmmarCSE commented.

Hope it helps

**EDIT** some text about the difference between jquery methods success() and done() :

[jQuery ajax success callback function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition/14754681#14754681)

Comment: .done() solved the problem... Thank you.It's weird because I've used before without .done() without problems.

Comment: $get and $ajax are differente... I also had crazy days with that... :) happy to see you solved!!

Comment: I think it´s due to ajax xhr errors. similar to done() there is a success method, that runs when the petition is ok. Done will run always. Adding an edit to clarify

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 $(document).on("click",".load",function(b){
  b.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
   method:'get',
   url : '/url/get.php', 
   data : '{id:123}',
   dataType: 'json', //json,html any you will return from backend
   success:function(a){
       $("#result").html(a);
     }


   })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$r = json_decode($data);

instead of $_GET in you php file, then print $r