# Database changes in radio button in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have written a code where the admin has the access to change the general users from active to inactive and vice-versa. So I want to update the database if the radio button is changed from active to inactive.

Here is the code:

```
    <%
    while (rs.next()) {
        String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
        String lastname = rs.getString("lastname");
        String email = rs.getString("email");
        String password = rs.getString("password");
        String age = rs.getString("age");
        String sex = rs.getString("sex");
        String haddress = rs.getString("haddress");
        String oaddress = rs.getString("oaddress");
        String phonenumber = rs.getString("phonenumber");
        String flag = rs.getString("flag");
        Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                   ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);


    %>



        <tr>
            <td>
              Name:  <% out.println(firstname); %> <% out.println(lastname); %>  

            </td>
            <td>
                <% if (flag.equals("A")){ %>

                Active: <input type="radio" value="A" name="<% out.println(email); %>"  onclick="<% stmt1.executeUpdate("update assignment set flag='A' where email='"+email+"'");
                               System.err.println("A"+email); %>
       alert('changed to active');" checked>
                Inactive: <input type="radio" value="I" name="<% out.println(email); %>" onclick="<% stmt1.executeUpdate("update assignment set flag='I' where email='"+email+"'");
                               System.err.println("I"+email); %>
       alert('changed to inactive');">
               <%
                    }else if(flag.equals("I")){%>

                Active: <input type="radio" value="A"  name="<% out.println(email); %>" onclick="<% stmt1.executeUpdate("update assignment set flag='A' where email='"+email+"'");
                               System.err.println("A"+email); %>
       alert('changed to active');">
                Inactive: <input type="radio" value="I" name="<% out.println(email); %>" onclick="<% stmt1.executeUpdate("update assignment set flag='I' where email='"+email+"'");
                               System.err.println("I"+email); %>
       alert('changed to inactive');" checked>
```

But in output, when I change one radio button, all the queries run automatically, updating the database to I for all the data in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using onclick, you need to invoke a ajax call and update the response . You should not use like onclick="<%SOME SQL Query%>". That is why it's updating all the rows.

Step 1: 
" onclick="updatestatus(this.value, '<% out.println(email); %>')"/>

Step 2 : 
Add Jquery lib and add a JS function

```
    function updatestatus(statuschg, email) {
       /*ajax call to some update-status.jsp with email and current value needs to be passed */
        //ajax code goes here ...
         $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "update-status.jsp", //this is my servlet
            data: "email=" +email"&status="+statuschg,
            success: function(msg){

                alert(msg);
            }
         });
    }
```

Ref: How to invoke ajax call [How to pass parameters in GET requests with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576548/how-to-pass-parameters-in-get-requests-with-jquery)

step 3: 
i) In update-status.jsp,Establish db connection
ii) receive parameters of the email address and current status.
iii) Execute the Query 
stmt1.executeUpdate("update assignment set flag='+status+' where email='"+email+"'")
iv) out.println("Updated");

Comment: you can do that but page refresh happens and you need to retain the position. With out ajax, it won't be interactive / better user experience when the entire page reloads / refreshes. You can use like onchange="pagename.jsp?email="+email+"&status="+this.value; On refresh, get the values and do the db manipulation.But this will refresh every time, when u opt / change the opted value for each row.

Comment: can you please elaborate the code for this? For me, regular refreshment won't be a problem.

Comment: 1. <input type="radio" value="A" name="<% out.println(email); %>"  onchange="pageupdate('<% out.println(email); %>', '"+this.value+"');"/>         2. In JS logic function pageupdate(emailid, optedval) { location.href='targetpage.jsp?email='+emailid+'&optedval='+optedval; } 3. in the JSP logic, use update query to receive the value and update it.

Comment: I am having trouble with :  '"+this.value+"'

Comment: use this, there is a typo in previous. <input type="radio" value="A" name="<% out.println(email); %>" onchange="pageupdate('<% out.println(email); %>', this.value);"/>

Comment: I have edited the code as: 
 Active: <input type="radio" value="A" name="<% out.println(email); %>" id="<% out.println(email); %>" onchange="pageupdatecta('<% out.println(email); %>', this.value);" checked>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageupdatecta(emailid, optedval) {
       location.href='changeToActive.jsp?email='+emailid+'&optedval='+o‌​ptedval; 
   } 

And I have created another jsp called changeToActive. Can you please tell me how to receive the values in jsp?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different codes. The key is to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is send to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

I.e. in your

```
onclick="<% stmt1.executeUpdate("update assignment set flag='I' where email='"+email+"'"); System.err.println("I"+email); %> alert('changed to inactive');"
```

the `<% stmt1.executeUpdate("update assignment set flag='I' where email='"+email+"'"); System.err.println("I"+email); %>` part is executed on the server **when the page is generated**, and only the `alert('changed to inactive');` waits in browser until the input field is clicked.

What you need is [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/3511123).

**Side note:** Do not put Java code into JSP, use MVC pattern, or at least put the code into an "util" class and call the class from JSP.

Comment: @LavinaChhabra Would you mind to upvote my answer then?