# execute cURL request from Jquery AJAX while passing variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, get

I've researched a lot about PHP cURL and already know a fair amount of Jquery Ajax however what i'm trying to do isn't straight down the line. I'm making an API call using an API Login button that returns a users nickname.

I then make an ajax request to a php file containing the curl paramaters within which i want to pass the users nickname.

## RESOLVED

Using `data` in the AJAX Request i was able to successfully send the javascript variable `nickname` as a parameter.

The variable was then accessible via `$nickname = $_GET['nickname'];` in the cURL PHP file.

**Thank you** to **rollstuhlfahrer** for providing the solution marked below.

---

#### Ajax Request:

```
var nickname = API.getUserInfo().value.nickname;
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: "/curl-php-file.php",
  cache: false,
  data: {
    nickname: nickname, // Sends data as a URL paramater
  }
  success: function(response) {
    // Data
    var data = response.data.data;
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(response, val) {
    console.log("AJAX Request Failed");
  }
});
```

#### cURL PHP File:

```
$nickname = $_GET['nickname']; // Gets data from AJAX
require_once("../../../../../wp-load.php");
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://.../?nickname=' . $nickname,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
  'Accept: application/json',
  'Authorization: MYTOKEN'
)
));
$resp   = curl_exec($curl);
wp_send_json_success(json_decode($resp));
curl_close($curl);
exit;
```

Comment: Not clear where you have access to this nickname. Step 1 needs more detail

Comment: Prior to the AJAX request i have access to the variable.

Comment: Where? In client or server side?

Comment: Client side, it's a javascript variable. I have access to it before the AJAX request and am able to pass it as a string in the URL using the answer below by @rollstuhlfahrer however the php script isn't reading it using the _GET procedure

Comment: Then show the relevant code used to acquire nickname which is basically the point of the first comment

Comment: If u read the comments below.. i'm already able to pass the variable as a paramater using data in the ajax request, the issue is that the php curl file isnt processing it.

Comment: None of that is shown in question itself

Comment: I've updated the question with the updated code from the suggestions below and for your benefit i've added the line before the ajax request where u can see the variable being set. As mentioned in the original question, user connects the API via login and the variable is stored from the data returned prior to the AJAX request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `GET`, you can just pass it along as a query parameter:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: "/curl-php-file.php?nickname=" + nickname,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {
    // Data
    var data = response.data.data;
    console.log(data);
  },
}
```

Another option. This has the beauty if built-in character encoding:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/curl-php-file.php",
  method: "get", 
  data: { 
    nickname: nickname,
  },
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15576581/1392490)

Then in your PHP code, you retrieve the passed parameter:

```
$nickname = $_GET['nickname'];
```

And append it to your URL:

```
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://.../?nickname=' . $nickname,
```

You should do some checking, if the nickname is a valid one before sending it off via curl.

Comment: beautiful, will try this now and get back!

Comment: If the answer satisfies your question, please don't hesitate to accept it

Comment: I really thought the $_GET['nickname']; suggestion would work but its not working. Returns: "Required String parameter 'nickname' is not present"

Comment: Have you checked, that the ajax call is passing the nickname? - You can see that in the developer tools in your browser.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion fixed everything, it took a second for my js to recache!