# How to Pass Data in ajax call using GET Method in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, qunit

I am writing Unit Test Case In javascript using qunit. i am calling one URL using ajax call and using GET method but it is not calling URL. I am Providing Test below:

```
 QUnit.test( "Importing Grid", function(assert) {
    var done = assert.async();    
    var data = {
        "info": {"view":"LATEST","mode": 1,"memberId": 1001,"baselineId": -1}
    }
    console.log(cuboid_id+" : "+cuboid_name);
    $.ajax({
        url: Globals.baseURL + "rest/grid/"+cuboid_id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result){                
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));                                                       
            assert.equal(result !=null,true,"Response should not be null");               
            assert.equal(result[0].error,"Whitebaord ID NOT FOUND","InValid Whiteboard ID");               
            done();
        }
    });
});
```

Can someone suggest me what to change in ajax Call??
I tried [this stackoverflow answer but it is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters in GET requests with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576548/how-to-pass-parameters-in-get-requests-with-jquery)

Comment: i tried that but it is not working

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui here he is not passing parameters as key value pair but instead JSON object.

Comment: try removing dataType and data fields from ajax.
if you want to send data in get, append those fields in url, or use post.

Comment: Passing data in body of get request is useless https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body. This will create TypeError as it will fail to execute fetch on window. You should use query param in the url to send data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: Globals.baseURL + "rest/grid/"+cuboid_id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "application/json",
    data: {some_query_var : JSON.stringify(data)},
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(result){
        console.log("***********************++++++++++++++*************************");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));                                                       
        //assert.equal(result !=null,true,"Response should not be null");               
        //assert.equal(result[0].error,"Whitebaord ID NOT FOUND","InValid Whiteboard ID");
        assert.equal(1,1); 
        done();
    }
});
```

"dataType json" in ajax jquery doesn't mean for formating JSON string in "data" attribute .. 
you still need the query variable passing in the "data" attribute. wich is in this is case i use some_query_var.