# Pass parametrs to get request

Tags: javascript, yii2

I have get reqquest like this (API key is change):

> http://geohelper.info/api/v1/cities?apiKey=dddff&locale[lang]=uk&filter[name]=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7

In the get request I need to pass a parameter filter[name].

My attempts:

```
$.get(
                "http://geohelper.info/api/v1/cities?apiKey=ssss&locale[lang]=uk",
                {
                    filter[name]: input,
                },
            )
```

But in that case, return the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: findCity is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.oninput

How to pass the parameters?

Comment: In documentation http://geohelper.info/ru/documentation/rules check example
You just need to replace '[' with %5B and ']' with %5D.
In your case "http://geohelper.info/api/v1/cities?apiKey=ssss&locale%5Blang%5D=uk" try this using your apiKey and paste this url in browser and check

Comment: Hello, I think you are looking similar like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576548/how-to-pass-parameters-in-get-requests-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks. It is work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters in GET requests with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576548/how-to-pass-parameters-in-get-requests-with-jquery)