# jQuery doesn't posts data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm stucked here for an hour now, I've searched in some topics on stackoverflow but nothing.

I have this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.qty').keyup(function () {
    var $me = $(this),
        $parent = $me.parent('div'),
        total = parseInt($me.attr("data-price"));

    if (isNumber($me.val()) && $me.val() > 0) {
        total = total * $me.val();
    }
    $parent.find('.price').html(total);

    updateTotal();
});

function isNumber (n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function updateTotal () {
    var total = 0;

    $('.qty').each(function () {
        var $me = $(this);

        if (isNumber($me.val()) && $me.val() > 0) {
            total += $me.val() * parseInt($me.attr("data-price"));
        }        
    });

    $('#total').text(total);
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'./s.php',
    data:'price='+total,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
    });
}

updateTotal();
    </script>
```

I want to send the price to the s.php page from the same folder but when I type `echo $_POST['price'];` I get the undefined index error. `var_dump($_POST['price'])` returns null. The result from the pop-up page is good, but is not passed to that page.

Comment: You're submitting a character (with all the headers and baggage it takes) with each user key pressed? I think that's a bit over the top of the possibilities of modern internet connections.

Comment: maybe instead of data:'price='+total to use data:{price:total} I dont know...?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using ``method: POST`` instead of ``type: POST``?

Comment: Besides, right click, Inspect element, go to the tab of console and right click there and select "store log". Then attempt again and see what data is actually being sent (clicking on each request that will appear there).

Comment: @ShengSlogar no...read the `$.ajax ` docs

Comment: inspect the requests in browser console network tab to see what is actually sent

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia in the console is only Content loaded http://localhost/test/price.php

Comment: try `data: {price : total},`

Comment: @charlietfl my bad, haven't programmed in a while because I'm away from my computer. I posted my comment and went to check the docs when your commented appeared. :P

Comment: @charlietfl http://i.imgur.com/xZAMg0l.png

Comment: @adeneo my script stops working if i put `data: { price : total},`

Comment: Did you replace the `data:'price='+total,` with that line ?

Comment: @marius According to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066070/using-jquery-to-make-a-post-how-to-properly-supply-data-parameter  adeneos tip should work

Comment: ajax looks good...something wrong in php

Comment: @adeneo tried again and worked, but the data is still not printed by the php's echo.

Comment: Then post the PHP code as well.

Comment: It is posted in the first post: `<?php echo $_POST['price']; ?>`

Comment: And what do you get in the alert ?

Comment: The correct value every time the total price is updated

Comment: So what's the problem ?

Comment: You do realize it's asynchronous, you can't use the data outside the success function ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you when you use POST to the server send a JSON object.
what you did works for GET method, URL will look like "s.php?total=1000".

try this:

```
var toSend= {
    total: total
};
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'./s.php',
    data: toSend,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```